# Add startsWith in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

IE 11 does not support `startsWith` with strings. ([Look here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/))

How do you add a prototype so that it supports the method?

Comment: For future reference and to hopefully help future searches: The error that appears in IE is:

`TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'startsWith'`

Answer (score 71):

Straight from the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith), here's the polyfill:

```
if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
    Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'startsWith', {
        value: function(search, rawPos) {
            var pos = rawPos > 0 ? rawPos|0 : 0;
            return this.substring(pos, pos + search.length) === search;
        }
    });
}
```

This is safe to use in any browser.  If the method already exists, this code will see that and do nothing.  If the method does not exist, it will add it to the String prototype so it is available on all strings.

You just add this to one of your JS files in some place where it executes at startup and before you attempt to use `.startsWith()`.

If you want a polyfill version that follows the specification in its entirety, including all possible error checks, you can get that [here](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/String.prototype.startsWith), but you will probably have to use that with a bundler in the browser because of the way the polyfill is spread out among several files.

Comment: Do you just add it straight to the JS file?

Comment: people should def look there they usually always have a nice polyfill

Comment: @SandahAung yes before you want to use it

Comment: substr() function is considered a legacy function according to mozilla developer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr. If possible, use the substring() method instead (Recommended by MDN).

Comment: @fatih - MDN has apparently updated their polyfill to use `.substring()` so I edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @jfriend00, I've appreciated your quick response and good intention to update your code, so I've upvoted your answer instead my previous downvote.

Comment: FWIW, this polyfill isn't fully spec compliant. IMO better to simply declare it as a global function so you don't have potentially different behavior depending on whether the polyfill is used (or use a [compliant polyfill](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/String.prototype.startsWith)).

Comment: @snarf -  I added a link to that spec-polyfill to my answer if that's what someone wants (slower and more complicated and probably requires using a bundler for use in the browser).  Are there any differences in implementation besides the precise behavior in certain error conditions?  And, I wouldn't recommend declaring a global function, not in these days of modular development and the corresponding good move away from globals.

Comment: Then don't use a global function. Use a ponyfill or a utility class.

Answer (score 15):

Found an easier way to fix this,

```
function startsWith(str, word) {
    return str.lastIndexOf(word, 0) === 0;
}
```

like wise to find the endswith use below code,

```
function endsWith(str, word) {
    return str.indexOf(word, str.length - word.length) !== -1;
}
```

---

Links to [browser](https://caniuse.com/?search=lastIndexOf) [support](https://caniuse.com/?search=indexOf).

Comment: Need to check first if the function exists or not?

Comment: IndexOf functions are there, I have tested this.

Comment: Sure, but you don't want to use the polyfill if the browser supports the functionality natively? Don't mean testing for `indexOf`, but `endsWith`

Comment: I'm not sure there is. However, in 2017 there was no. if you added it now it will just get overridden by this.

Comment: Yeah it's very much supported by modern browsers :-)

Answer (score 3):

I've been using this polyfill:

```
if (typeof String.prototype.startsWith != 'function') {
    String.prototype.startsWith = function(prefix) {
        return this.slice(0, prefix.length) == prefix;
    };
}
```

Comment: FWIW, this polyfill isn't fully spec compliant. IMO better to simply declare it as a global function so you don't have potentially different behavior depending on whether the polyfill is used (or use a [compliant polyfill](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/String.prototype.startsWith)).

Comment: @snarf can you elaborate or post a link to the full spec? This code could be put in a global function.

Comment: MDN reference has a link to the specification. And yes, it *could* be a global function (or better yet a ponyfill), but my point is that it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I've reviewed and edited my answer. I believe that my code is now much more appropriate than before.

If your browser supports built-in 'startsWith' function then that built-in function will be use. Additionally I've included 'endsWith' also.

```js
if (typeof String.prototype.startsWith !== 'function') {
   String.prototype.startsWith = function(searchString, position) { 
       position = position || 0;
       return this.substring(position,  position + searchString.length) === searchString;
   }
}


if (typeof String.prototype.endsWith !== 'function') {
   String.prototype.endsWith = function(searchString, strtLength) { 
      strtLength = (strtLength === undefined || strtLength > this.length)? this.length : strtLength;   
      return this.substring(strtLength - searchString.length, strtLength) === searchString;
   }
}

  

/* usage */

let str = 'To be, or not to be, that is the question.'

console.log(str.startsWith('To be'))          // true
console.log(str.startsWith('not to be'))      // false
console.log(str.startsWith('not to be', 10))  // true

let str2 = 'To be, or not to be, that is the question.'
console.log(str2.endsWith('question.'))  // true
console.log(str2.endsWith('to be'))      // false
console.log(str2.endsWith('to be', 19))  // true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!String.prototype.endsWith) {
    String.prototype.endsWith = function (text) {
        return this.indexOf(text, this.length - text.length) !== -1;
    };
}

if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
    String.prototype.startsWith = function (text) {
        return this.lastIndexOf(text, 0) === 0;
    };
}
```